# Deobfuscating WPF obfuscated code

Tags: decompilation, decryption, debuggers, deobfuscation, .net

The project uses **WPF :** What should i do for XAML links de4dot  supporting that ?

I have been trying to deobfuscate an encrypted code for days but no matter what I did, I bypassed the debugger detection with kernel32dll in it, but since all other classes are linked and referenced to each other, I need to fix all the naming otherwise I cannot compile where I want.

I used **de4dot** and the program does not open for some reason I do not know if I deobfus with **de4dot**.

When I deobfuscate with **SAE ("Simple Assembly Browser")** the program does not open, just like de4dot.

I compiled and bought all the external libraries used by the program, there is nothing missing on that side.

How do you think I can overcome this?

[image: NameSpaces]

[image: Classes]

[image: ClassEntrance]